# No promo codes in iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, promotion-code

Why I can't see promo codes link in my panel?
In previous version of iTunes Connect panel they were available.
The help says you can't see codes in you are not admin, but I am admin!

Comment: Is the selected version of the app already approved?

Answer (score 0):

Go to particular app in iTunes Connect and at the bottom of the "Version" section there is a subsection called "Additional Information" there you can see "Promo Codes"

Comment: This used to be true, as of 10/22/2015 iTunes Connect has moved it again under the Features tab -> Promo Codes.

Answer (score 0):

iTunes Connect has moved the location here the promo codes are generated.

To generate promo codes as of 10/22/2015 select the app -> Features -> Promo codes

[image]